# Logical error in PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, prepared-statement

What I'm trying to do is, to generate nav menu like

```
 <ul>
   <li>
     <ul>
...........
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

from db, with one and only query. But onceI execute following function, it doesn't stop. (Seems there is logic error). Please take a  look, what's wrong

```
<?php

function generateMenu($parent, $level, $menu, $utype) {
    global $db;

    $tree = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("select id, parent, name FROM navigation WHERE menu=? AND user_type=?") or die($db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $menu, $utype) or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);

    $stmt->store_result();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

// the following creates a bind_result string with an argument for each column in the query
// e.g. $stmt->bind_result($results["id"], $results["foo"], $results["bar"]);
    $bindResult = '$stmt->bind_result(';
    while ($columnName = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $bindResult .= '$results["' . $columnName->name . '"],';
    }
    $bindResult = rtrim($bindResult, ',') . ');';

// executes the bind_result string
    eval($bindResult);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    while (list($id, $parent, $name) = $results) {
        $tree[$id] = array('name' => $name, 'children' => array(), 'parent' => $parent);
        if (!array_key_exists($tree[$parent]['children'][$id])) {
            $tree[$parent]['children'][$id] = $id;
        }
    }

    print_r($tree);
}

?>
```

Comment: Don't use eval: `eval($bindResult);`. *eval()* is also known as *evil()*

Comment: And what do you suggest?

Comment: @Tural: Try using `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: added a suggestion as an answer. It might solve your problem

Comment: Undefined offset: 1,2,3 online list($id, $parent, $name) = $results;

Comment: Oh my root menu items' parents are 0, maybe that causes problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the issue, but I'd suggest using [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) instead of `eval` to call `bind_result`.

```
$bindResult = array();
while ($columnName = $meta->fetch_field()) {
   // Needs to passed by reference, so that it creates the $results array correctly
   $bindResult[] = &$results[$columnName->name];
}
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $bindResult);
```

EDIT: Your issue is that `$sql->fetch()` needs to be called for each row, not just once.  The code loops forever because you keep reading the same row.  Try this:

```
function generateMenu($parent, $level, $menu, $utype) {
    global $db;

    $tree = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("select id, parent, name FROM navigation WHERE menu=? AND user_type=?") or die($db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $menu, $utype) or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);

    $stmt->store_result();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    $bindResult = array();
    $results = array();
    while ($columnName = $meta->fetch_field()) {
       // Needs to passed by reference, so that it creates the $results array correctly
       $bindResult[] = &$results[$columnName->name];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $bindResult);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        list($id, $parent, $name) = $results;
        $tree[$id] = array('name' => $name, 'children' => array(), 'parent' => $parent);
        if (!array_key_exists($tree[$parent]['children'][$id])) {
            $tree[$parent]['children'][$id] = $id;
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();

    print_r($tree);
}
```

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: Remove the code from `$bindResult = '$stmt->bind_result(';` to `eval($bindResult);`, and put this there instead.

Comment: Undefined variable: results on line `$bindResult[] = $results[$columnName->name];`

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: Try changing that line to `$bindResult[] = &$results[$columnName->name];`.

Comment: tried, once I execute modified function, it doesn't stop, without any error, just works all time.

Comment: @Rocket: I'm not getting how would this help. If he has no *$results*, he can't pass it by reference

Comment: @Martin: PHP will create a reference to nothing, and then create the array when it's needed.  It works.  It's the same as doing `$a[0] = 34;`.  This works even though you never did `$a = array();`.

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: I've figured out your issue, give me a minute to append my answer.

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: I've included a full function in my answer, try that.

Comment: : Undefined offset: 1,2,3 online `list($id, $parent, $name) = $results;`

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: Try printing `$results` (using `print_r($results)`) to make sure it's returning correctly.

Comment: tried right after ` call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $bindResult);` Got result `Array ( [id] => [parent] => [name] => ) 1`

Comment: Oh my root menu items' parents are `0`, maybe that causes problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5213/discussion-between-tural-teyyuboglu-and-rocket)

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: I am now, still need help?

Comment: Please move protracted conversations to chat. Thanks :)